# windows phone 8.1 How to run resource intensive tasks uninterrupted?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I need to upload close to 4Gb of data from external storage (SD card) to cloud. Phone will be on Wi-fi with power outlet connection.

Should I use Back Ground Transfer (BTS) or Resource Intensive Task (RIT). MSDN says RIT stops after 10 minutes which might interrupt my upload.

I've heard BTS isn't reliable. I'm kinda stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It will be deployed to the Enterprise phone store. So I guess I've some flexibility of not deploying it in Windows phone store.

*Also does BTS work under lock screen?*

Comment: My preference would be to go with BTS whose main purpose is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting Windows Phone 8.1, you should use the [BackgroundUploader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx) class. It is effectively unconstrained while the device is on WiFi and connected to AC power and will continue to run even if the device is locked.

For Windows Phone 8, your options are limited unless you can break the data into smaller chunks. BTS enforces [a set of constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_BackgroundTransferPolicies) on upload/download size that would preclude your scenario (maximum upload over AC/WiFi is 100mb) and resource-intensive tasks do run the risk of being too short-lived to complete your full upload.